# IOS Xcode Build Error

Tags: ios, xcode

On building an App, I have received the following error:

> Code Sign error: The file "YES" couldn't be opened because there is no
>   such file.: (null)

Steps that I have already taken to solve the issue:

1. Deleted [~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData]
2. Clean & Build
3. renewal of certificate, provisioning profile

See the picture below.

[image]

I don't know why this error is occurring and how can I fix it?

Further info, I am using Xcode Version 7.3.3 on Mac OS Version El Captain. I am developing for iOS Version IOS 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You might have provided the **"YES"** as filename OR **"YES"** as value anywhere in your project. This is
>   not allowed since it is pre-reserved word.
>
> So you need to have **different name/value in your project**.

Comment: Fixed. Thank's you info.plist file [Code Signing Entitlements] value "YES" modify to ""

Comment: Yup..! Great job@@

Answer (score 0):

`Yes` is a reserved word, try calling the class and file name `YesFile`.

Comment: Fixed. Thank's you info.plist file [Code Signing Entitlements] value "YES" modify to ""